# Vectorial functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y)=\sin(x^2-y^2)$ and let $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by: $g(x,y)=(x+y,x-y)$. My questions is:

1) Calculate partial derivatives of $f\circ g$ and $d (f\circ g)$ at $(x,y)$.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What did you try? Does your textbook say anything about this?

Comment: @vrugtehagel. I have only this formula in my course $d(g\circ f)=dg(f(a))\circ df(a)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is the chain rule, which is what you have.

$$ \frac{d}{d x}\Bigr|_{x=x_0} (f \circ g)(x,y_0) = \underbrace{\left \langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Bigr|_{g(x_0,y_0)}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Bigr|_{g(x_0,y_0)}\right\rangle}_{df(g(x_0,y_0))} \cdot \underbrace{\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\Bigr|_{(x_0,y_0)}}_{dg(x_0,y_0)}$$

$$ \frac{d}{d y}\Bigr|_{y=y_0} (f \circ g)(x_0,y) = \left \langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Bigr|_{g(x_0,y_0)}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Bigr|_{g(x_0,y_0)}\right\rangle \cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\Bigr|_{(x_0,y_0)}$$

Now just recall that in terms of the canonical basis the differential $d(f \circ g)$ is given by,

$$\\$$

$$d(f \circ g)(x_0,y_0) = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial (f \circ g)}{\partial x} \Bigr|_{(x_0,y_0)} & \frac{\partial (f \circ g)}{\partial y} \Bigr|_{(x_0,y_0)}\end{pmatrix}$$

$\textbf{Comment}$: Remember that $g(x,y) = (f_1(x,y), f_2(x,y))$ and so $\partial g/ \partial x, \partial g/\partial y$ are vectors that you get from differentiating the coordinate functions with respect to $x,y$.

Comment: No problem. You just have to remember this version, $$\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t = t_0} (f \circ c)(t) = \nabla f(c(t_0)) \cdot \frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=t_0}c$$